# I'm confused about GNU Assembler starting and ending section in a function declaration

Tags: x86, gnu, assembly

I have been recently learning x86 assembly language via GNU Assembler on Ubuntu by the book Programming Ground UP at somewhere on the internet.

There are always 2 sections that's a "Must-Have" when creating a function:

At the beginning, it's considered to save old %ebp and set new frame pointer

> pushl %ebp
>
> movl  %esp,%ebp

At the end, it's used to restore old %ebp and pop out return address

> movl %ebp, %esp
>
> popl %ebp
>
> ret

please help me know what's really happen and what's that used for.
- Why they must copy the bottom-most stack pointer to %ebp to set a new frame pointer?
- And why the must copy back the %ebp to %esp when done ?
- When copy without `( )` is that just an address ?

Thanks.

Comment: Function prologues and epilogues are usually generated only by compilers, and nowadays even then they need tpo be explicitly enabled on some architectures. For a programmer writing some assembly its very unusual. So they are far from "must-have"

Comment: preamble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147623/trying-to-understand-the-main-disassembly-first-instructions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a function perilogue.  The [Frequently Given Answer giving the gen on function perilogues](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/function-perilogues.html) explains what's happening, stack frames, and the frame pointer register.

Comment: THanks, the link is very useful. Perhaps, at 1st I didn't know what they call it.

Comment: I've downvoted this because it is effectively a link only answer that offers no information. If the link dies this answer is unusable. I'd remove the downvote if a summary of the information that answers the OPs specific question appeared directly in the answer