# Scanf a char pointer in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, att

So I have a task to do, which requires from me to `scanf` a `char*` in assembly. I tried this code:

```
.data
INPUT_STRING:   .string "Give me a string: "
SCANF_STRING:   .string "%s"
PRINTF_STRING:  .string "String: %s\n"

.text
    .globl main
    .type main, @function
main:
    leal 4(%esp), %ecx
    andl $-16, %esp
    pushl -4(%ecx)
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl %ecx
    subl $32, %esp
    pushl $INPUT_STRING 
    call printf #printf("Give me a string: ")
    addl $4, %esp
    pushl -12(%ebp) # char*
    pushl $SCANF_STRING # "%s"
    call scanf scanf("%s", char*)
    addl $8, %esp    
    pushl -12(%ebp)
    pushl PRINTF_STRING
    call printf #printf("String: %s\n")
    addl $16, %esp
    movl -4(%ebp), %ecx   
    xorl %eax, %eax
    leave
    leal -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
```

It writes down first printf correctly, then it waits for input (so `scanf` works), but then when I enter anything -> `Segmentation fault`.

I know, that the `char*` should be somehow initialized, but how can I do it from the assembly level?

I am compiling it on Manjaro 64 bit, with `gcc -m32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GCC's stack-alignment code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147623/trying-to-understand-gccs-complicated-stack-alignment-at-the-top-of-main-that-c) on entry to main is over-complicated:

```
leal 4(%esp), %ecx
andl $-16, %esp
pushl -4(%ecx)
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
pushl %ecx
subl $32, %esp
...
leave
leal -4(%ecx), %esp
ret
```

Do it so:

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $32, %esp        # Space for 32 local bytes
andl $-16, %esp       # Alignment by 16
...
leave
ret
```

The version of the i386 System V ABI used on modern Linux *does* guarantee/require 16-byte stack alignment before a `call`, so you could have re-aligned with 3 pushes (including the `push %ebp`) instead of an `and`.  Unlike x86-64, most i386 library functions don't get compiled to use `movaps` or `movdqa` 16-byte aligned load/store on locals in their stack space, so you can often get away with unaligning the stack like you're doing with `PUSH`es before scanf.  (`ESP % 16 == 0` when you `call printf` the first time, though; that's correct.)

---

You want to use 12 bytes of the local stack frame for the string. `scanf` needs the start address of those 12 bytes. The address for that area isn't known at compile time. A `-12(%ebp)` gives you the value at this address, not the address itself. `LEA` is the instruction to calculate an address. So you have to insert this instruction to get the address at run time and to pass it to the C function:

```
leal -12(%ebp), %eax
pushl %eax # char*
```

And this is the working example (minor mistakes also corrected):

```
.data
INPUT_STRING:   .string "Give me a string: "
SCANF_STRING:   .string "%11s"      ##### Accept only 11 characters (-1 because terminating null)
PRINTF_STRING:  .string "String: %s\n"

.text
    .globl main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $32, %esp

    mov $32, %ecx
    mov %esp, %edi
    mov $88, %al
    rep stosb

    pushl $INPUT_STRING
    call printf                         # printf("Give me a string: ")
    addl $4, %esp

    leal -12(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax                          # char*
    pushl $SCANF_STRING                 # "%s"
    call scanf                          # scanf("%s", char*)
    addl $8, %esp

    leal -12(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax                          # char*
    pushl $PRINTF_STRING            ##### '$' was missing
    call printf                         # printf("String: %s\n")
    addl $8, %esp                   ##### 16 was wrong. Only 2 DWORD à 4 bytes were pushed

    leave
    ret
```

Comment: But then, you put up a `char*` on `-12(%ebp)` and what if it has a really big length? Where does it store all the chars?

Comment: @Frynio: In the stack. It's a part of "subl $32, %esp". For a really big or variable length you would use `malloc` like in C. If you're using the C library - think like a C programmer :-)

Comment: Yes, I know. But then what's the limit for the number of characters?

Comment: The stack sets the limit. Last time when I overflowed it the default value was in Windows 1 MB and in Linux 8 MB. Your personal limit is `-12(%ebp)` = 11 characters + terminating null. Because the stack frame is not used for other variables in your example, you can increase it up to `-32(%ebp)` = 31 characters + terminator. You want 999 characters and one null:: `subl $1000, %esp` and `-1000(%ebp)`

Comment: The `leal 4(%esp), %ecx` stuff is from an older GCC version, duplicating a whole stack frame including a return address.  [Trying to understand gcc's complicated stack-alignment at the top of main that copies the return address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1147623) .  It's not necessary at all with a modern glibc (CRT) and kernel that preserve the incoming 16-byte stack alignment from `_start`, but `gcc -m32` is conservative about `main` even when targeting modern Linux.  Stack alignment by 16 *is* needed in the version of the i386 System V ABI used on Linux, though.